# Driver not found when calling "doctrine create-db"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, doctrine-1.2

I didn't know why but, I'm not able to perform this command with doctrine create-db . 
As you can see, my pdo and pdo_mysql is activated.

```
php -i | grep 'ini'
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/suhosin.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini
Supported handlers => cdb cdb_make db4 inifile flatfile
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilterIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SimpleXMLIterator, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplObjectStorage, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException
```

**here is my php version**

```
php -v
PHP 5.2.6-3ubuntu4.6 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Sep 16 2010 19:52:51)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2008 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Care to share an error message and the entire command you run?

Answer (score -1):

What code are you trying to run? can you submit it? did you get the above error from /var/log/ inspection?

What happens if you try to run the test code for doctrine:

```
<?php

// test.php

require 'lib/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader();
$classLoader->setBasePath('Doctrine', __DIR__ . '/lib');
?>
```

Comment: ^^ what he said.  Also you didn't provide an answer in your answer, you just asked a question...  Should be a comment.